# Git Changes not showing changed files in only one solution in Visual Studio 2019

Tags: git, visual-studio, version-control

This is quite frustrating.
I have a folder with different solutions that I open in VS2019.
I have this one particular solution called DevApplication.sln, whichever file I modify in this solution it does not appear in Git Changes window. I even added new aspx page and that still did not appear.

I tried to modify files in different solution in the same folder, the changed file appears in Git Changes.

I already tried checking the gitignore file, I closed and reopened the Git changes tab, I restart visual studio, I restarted my laptop. Nothing worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

For a particular solution, new files and modified files are ignoring by git ignore file. Check gitignore file to check it.

When you added a new aspx file, if it is showing in Solution explorer, just right click on that file and  *Git -> add ignore file to source control*  will add the file to git changes window.